# PHP regex to insert '/' after a sequence of numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have several thousand strings in the format of

```
"12345This_is_awesome-2014.html"
```

What I need to do is insert a forward slash after the first sequence of numbers "12345"

I found a regex that will insert a forward slash after ever sequence of numbers

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\d\b)(?!,)/', '/', $string)
```

But I need to insert a forward slash only after the first sequence of numbers

The first sequence is not always the same length and sometimes it has one character on the front of it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
$string = preg_replace('~^(\D*\d+)(?!/)(?=\D|$)~', '$1/', $string)
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bI3kG8/2)

Comment: This works... [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b49fc17af361faeade3f9ab5cfe6e780ed743ea2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b49fc17af361faeade3f9ab5cfe6e780ed743ea2)

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gA3pT6/5)

sample code:

```
$re = "/(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)/";
$str = "12345This_is_awesome-2014.html";
$subst = '/';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

output:

```
12345/This_is_awesome-2014.html
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    \d                       digits (0-9)
  )                        end of look-behind
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    \D                       non-digits (all but 0-9)
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: is there any replace_all function in php?

Comment: don't know but it replaces just first one as per demo. replace all if used `g` flag in regex pattern.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes. `preg_replace()`, by default, replaces all the occurrences of pattern in the given text.

Comment: It works [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e8db332b929a711df94d28deecac10b3b67afd3](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e8db332b929a711df94d28deecac10b3b67afd3)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
preg_replace("/^\D*\d+/", "$0/", $string);
```

This will match any non-digits at the start, then your target digits, and add a slash after them. It won't affect numbers further along.